# What's the point of punching a guard more than once?

Tags: gunpoint

When I pounce on a guard from behind in Gunpoint, I have an option to punch him to knock him out. But after that I can apparently punch him again and again after that, spraying blood on the floor. Since a single punch is all it takes, is there any point for punching more beyond that, or is it purely for sadistic reasons?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, I found out: 10+ punches kill the guard. It increases the violence rating, but removes a witness. Depending on the preference of the mission giver, one may be preferable to the other.

Answer (score 2):

I think punching the guard more than once is more likely to kill him, therefore increasing your violence rating. Punching them once should be enough to knock guards out.

Comment: Only played the demo but it seems killing would also help get a better "Witnesses" rating. Dead men tell no tales. Not sure if it's worth the boost in Violence rating though.

Answer (score 2):

You actually get a bunch of funny messages, followed by an achievement if you punch a guard 100 times!

Answer (score 1):

10 punches to kill a guard, helpful for max violence request but not for minimum violence. Also, via Steam you can get an achievement for punching him a bunch of times.